# javascript wait until data is loaded

Tags: javascript, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have the following function

```
<script src='jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    function loaddata() {

    var div = $('#div');
        $.get('load_data.php', function(data) { 
            div.html(data);
            $('body, html').scrollTop(div[0].scrollHeight);
        });
    }
    loaddata();
    setInterval(loaddata, 1000);
});


window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(($(window).scrollTop() < 1) )
    {
        $.ajax({url: 'load_extra_data.php,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){ $('#div').prepend(html);
                    $(document).scrollTop(position);
        }})
    }
})

</script>
```

the problem is related to the function

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
```

The function load_extra_data.php provides the data that has to be added to the div.
I need to wait until the data from load_extra_data.php is fetched before scrolling a second time.

How can the problem be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a flag to tell you whether you have data loading, and don't ask for more data while the flag is set. Roughly:

```
var loading = false;                             // The flag, initially false
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if (!loading && $(window).scrollTop() < 1) {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− Checking the flag
        loading = true;                          // Setting the flag
        $.ajax({
            url: 'load_extra_data.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $('#div').prepend(html);
                $(document).scrollTop(position);
            },
            complete: function() {               // Clearing the flag when
                loading = false;                 // the request ends (whether
            }                                    // it succeeds or fails)
        });
    }
});
```

*(I've only used ES5 and earlier features in that, since your code didn't show signs having ES2015+ items in it. But in 2020, I'd certainly be writing to ES2015+ and transpiling if I really had to support obsolete environments that didn't support it.)*

Comment: this solution works if the data provided by load_extra_data.php contains no pictures. if  picture is present, the position of the scrollbar is wrong. any idea ?

Comment: The issue addressed above has nothing whatsoever to do with the content you're loading. If you have a new problem related to specific content, please post a new question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback function .done() of $.ajax(). Which will be executed after the data has loaded.

```js
$.ajax({url: 'load_extra_data.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){ $('#div').prepend(html);
    $(document).scrollTop(position);
}}).done(function() {
  // Executed after $.ajax fetch is done
})
```